# What happened to Marshall and Lily's bet?

Tags: plot-explanation, how-i-met-your-mother

In the end of *How I Met You Mother* Ted is seen going back to Robin. Marshall and Lily were forever waiting who is going to win the bet about Ted and Robin being together.

Technically Marshall won. But I don't remember them dealing with it or doing anything about it in the finale. Or did I miss something out? Or was it probably forgotten by the couple and so they did not mention it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**The scene that resolves the bet was cut for time.** In the last few seconds of the finale as aired, Ted gets back with Robin (or at least suggests it) and the show ends. But there *was* a scene that shows Lily paying Marshall over that bet, [according to Alyson Hannigan](http://www.ibtimes.com/how-i-met-your-mother-season-9-spoilers-why-was-series-finale-cut-short-alyson-hannigan-reveals-what).

> Hannigan took to Twitter to reveal what scenes were cut in addition to tying up some loose ends for fans. “I do believe Lily owes Marshall money, though,” one Twitter user wrote to Hannigan. **“YES & that scene was CUT!!!** :(((,” she replied.

In fact, [about 18 minutes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Last_Forever#Production) were cut from the finale for time constraints. [The season 9 DVD contains several deleted scenes, but I've yet to confirm that the scene resolving the bet is one of them.]

Comment: I guess than I need to get the season 9 dvd and see the deleted scenes too. Lots of important stuff seems to be cut-off. I kind of thought the last season was not so funny and just dragged for no reason. Thanks for the link.